# Simplify the radical in the quadratic formula?

Tags: java, quadratic

I am fairly new to java and need help writing the code that will simplify the quadratic formula. Right now my program truncates the two solutions to two decimal places. But I do not know how to simplify the square of the discriminant. For example, if the discriminant is 8, then I would want the program to output 2√2. Can please provide me with the code necessary to do this?

```
package quadraticprogram;

//This imports the DecimalFormat class, Scanner class, and all other Java classes.
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class QuadraticProgram {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a, A;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println ("Use integer value, enter minimum value of a:");
    a = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println ("Use integer value, enter maximum value of A:");
    A = scan.nextInt();
    Random generator = new Random();

    // Generate random integers in the range from a to A
    // and assign them to numa, numb, and numc
    double numa = generator.nextInt(A - a + 1) + a;
    double numb = generator.nextInt(A - a + 1) + a;
    double numc = generator.nextInt(A - a + 1) + a;

    System.out.println ("numa" + numa);
    System.out.println ("numb" + numb);
    System.out.println ("numc" + numc);

    // Define d as the discriminant and take its square root
    double d;
    d = ((numb*numb)-(4*numa*numc));
    double r = Math.sqrt(d);

    // Calculate the two solutions
    double s = ((-numb + r)/(2*numa));
    double S = ((-numb - r)/(2*numa));

    // Truncate the two solutions to two decimal places.
    DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat ("0.##");

    // If the discriminant is negative there are no real solutions.
    if (d<0) {
      System.out.println("No Real Solutions");
    } else  {
    // Print both solutions if the discriminant is not negative
      System.out.print(fmt.format(s));
      System.out.println("," + fmt.format(S));
    }
  }
}
```

Right now the program has the user input a minimum integer,a and a maximum integer, A. Then random double values, numa, numb, and numc are generated that are between a and A. Then the program calculates the discriminant, d, as a double. Then the square root the d is taken which is r. Then the program finishes calculating the two solutions s and S. Then the program prints the two solutions, if the discriminant is not less than 0, and truncates them to two decimal places.

Comment: I'm no math (or java) guy, so I'd be in the wrong place to advise you about your original question, but as a programmer, speaking generally, I'd STRONGLY suggest you rethink your variable naming strategy. 2 variables (A, a) holding different values and differing in name only by case is an absolute magnet for WTF type reactions a disaster for long term maintainability (should you ever write more complex programs for which that is a consideration). I'd suggest (a, b) or (a1, a2) instead.

Comment: Is there any reason to use doubles instead of ints or longs?  Floating-point numbers are more difficult to work with, and your example implies you want to print your solution using integers or fractions.

Answer (score 4):

The basic algorithm is pretty simple:

1. Factor the number in the discriminant
2. Take factors that appear twice out of the radical

Here's an example:

`sqrt(180) = sqrt(2*2*3*3*5) = 2*3*sqrt(5) = 6*sqrt(5)`

Note that this will not work if the discriminant is non-integral.

Comment: Also, be sure to check for `d < 0` before you take its square root.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing I understood your goal was to print the square root of the descriminant in a simplified fashion, this should work (I used ? instead of the sqrt symbol that I don't have time to look up how to print out):

```
     while(d%Math.pow(f, 2)!=0&&f>1){
        f--;
    }

    if(f>1&&d/Math.pow(f, 2)!=1){
        System.out.println(f+"?"+d/Math.pow(f, 2));
    }else{
        System.out.println(Math.sqrt(d));
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1.Not sure what you did but here is my solution.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class quadform {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    double a,b,c;

    Scanner takea = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter variable a");
    double inputa = takea.nextDouble();

    Scanner takeb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter variable b");
    double inputb = takeb.nextDouble();

    Scanner takec = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter variable c");
    double inputc = takec.nextDouble();


    a = inputa;
    b = inputb;
    c = inputc;


    double rootone,roottwo;
    double discriminant;
    double thefirstpart,thesecondpart;
    thefirstpart = Math.pow(b,2);
    thesecondpart =4 *a *c;
    discriminant = Math.sqrt(thefirstpart - thesecondpart);
    rootone = (-(b)+ discriminant)/(2 *(a)); 
    roottwo = (-(b)- discriminant)/(2 *(a));

    System.out.println("The first root (+) is: " + rootone);
    System.out.println("The second root(-) is: " + roottwo);




    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally think this would be the easiest way to have the right answers with the least amount of code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class ShortABC 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    float a = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please, give in variable a", "Input variable A", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE)), b = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please, give in variable b", "Input b", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE)), c = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please, give in variable c", "Input c", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE)), D = (float) (Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c)), x1 = (float) ((-b - Math.sqrt(D)/(2*a))), x2 = (float) ((-b + Math.sqrt(D)/(2*a)));//Input for all variables.
    if(D < 0) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No answers possible");//Output for answer(s). else if(D == 0) 
    else if(D == 0) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"One possible answer: " + x1);//Output for answer(s).
    else if(D > 0) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Two possible answers: " + x1 + " en " + x2);//Output for answer(s).
    }
}
```

I wouldn't know how to print the answers in spuareroots though. Good luck with that.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I essentially created a function to find the square factor of a square root and used that for everything else.

```
public static double sqFactor(double num) {
    double sqInt = 1;
    double lastInt=1;
    for (int i=2; i<=num;) {
        if (num%i==0) {
            num /= i;


            if (i==lastInt) {
                sqInt *= i;
                lastInt=1;
                i=1;
            }
            else lastInt=i;
            i=1;

        }

        i++;

    }
    return sqInt;
}

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("a =");
        double a = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("b =");
        double b = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("c =");
        double c = scan.nextDouble();

        double d = Math.pow(b, 2) -(4 * a * c);
        if (d<0) {
        d *= -1;
        System.out.println("Your roots are " + -b +" +- " + sqFactor(d) +"i sqrt" + d/sqFactor(d) );
        }
        else {
        double root1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
        double root2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);

        System.out.println("Your first root value is " + root1);
        System.out.println("Your second root value is " + root2);
        }



    }
```